# UIKit UILabel Color Based on User Appearance Setting in iPhone

Tags: ios

I have been working in SwiftUI for couple of months, which took care of light and dark mode for views on the screen. In my current UIKit app, everything looks fine on light mode but when the user iPhone settings are dark mode then the UILabel is not shown due to displaying while on white.

```
lazy var nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .label
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        return label
    }()
```

How can I make sure that the nameLabel looks readable in both dark and light mode in UIKit?

Answer (score 0):

`UIColor.label` is black in light mode and white in dark mode. To properly support both light and dark mode, whatever background is shown behind the label should be a light color in light mode and a dark color in dark mode.

Since you state that you end up with white on white in dark mode this means you are not allowing the background to go dark in dark mode.

You have two solutions:

1. Update the background color so it's a dark color in dark mode. This will allow the white text of dark mode to be visible.
2. If you need the white background in both light and dark mode then you want to force black text in both light and dark mode. So change `label.textColor = .label` to `label.textColor = .black`.